# How to add a text-field-placeholder using WTForms-Alchemy

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-wtforms

I'm currently using [WTForms-Alchemy](https://wtforms-alchemy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) for creating forms for my database models.

My User.py looks like this:

```
class User(UserMixin, db.Model, CreationDateMixin):
   __tablename__ = 'user'

   id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
   first_name = db.Column(db.String(50), info={
      'label': 'Firstname',
      'validators': validators.Length(min=3)
   })
```

For the Model I defined a form using WTForms-alchemy:

```
class EditProfileForm(ModelForm, FlaskForm):
   class Meta:
      model = User

   submit = SubmitField("Update")
```

And I'm using the form in a Jinja2 Template file like this:

```
{{ form.short_name }}
```

Is there a way to define a placeholder for the text input in the User.py class? I already tried adding a the parameter 'placeholder' to the info block but this didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

WTForms has an argument `render_kw` which is a dict describing arguments to pass to the render widget for the form object. [ https://wtforms.readthedocs.io/en/stable/fields.html#the-field-base-class ]

The info argument is a dict of arguments to pass to the WTForms functions so the solution is to pass a dict of another dict:

```
class User(UserMixin, db.Model, CreationDateMixin):
   __tablename__ = 'user'

   id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
   first_name = db.Column(db.String(50), info={
      'label': 'Firstname',
      'validators': validators.Length(min=3),
      'render_kw': {'placeholder': 'FIRST NAME'}
   })
```